# understanding a selector from within a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

For a raw_input sentence I must print out each word and it's type from a dict:

```
wordDict = {
            "directions": ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right'],
            "verbs": ['go', 'stop', 'eat', 'kill'],
            "stop_words": ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it'],
            "nouns": ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet'],
            "numbers": range(10)
            }

stuff = raw_input("Write sentence here > ")

words = stuff.split()

for wds in words:
    print (wordDict[wrd]), wrd
```

So if someone typed in "north go the bear 5" I'd receive output along the lines:

directions: north, verbs: go, stop_words: the, nouns: bear, numbers: 5

This is for a tutorial in Learn Python The Hard Way (exercise 48).

For each word how would I print out it's type and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of the words by iterating through your dictionary:

```
for word in words:
    for key,values in wordDict.items():
        if word in values:
            print key,word
```

For the numbers to work well, you need to convert these to strings:

```
"numbers": [str(n) for n in range(10)]
```

---

Following Raphaël's suggestion, an other way to get the type:

```
def get_type(word):
    for key,values in wordDict.items():
        if word in values:
            return key

for word in words:
    print word, get_type(word)
```

In this case it returns one type even if the same word exists in multiple lists. It handles the situation when the word is missing from all lists. Prints `None` in that case.

Comment: @Norbert I agree. Doug, by the way I feel like you're doing some assumptions that your list won't share elements. This won't probably be the case when your code will evolve, so Norbert code is ok but be prepared to get several "type" for one entry :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using your wordDict, as your keys are the words which are the values in your search dictionary, you would be in an advantage, if you transpose your dictionary aforehand.

This will make your lookup code less complex and readable.

Also, its important to note that, your words would be unique, as a single word cannot fall into multiple categories, so, you can easily use your words are keys and the category as values.

```
>>> wordDict = {
            "directions": ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right'],
            "verbs": ['go', 'stop', 'eat', 'kill'],
            "stop_words": ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it'],
            "nouns": ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet'],
            "numbers": range(10)
            }
>>> wordDict_transpose = {str(elem): key for key, value in wordDict.items() 
                          for elem in value}
>>> for word in words.split():
    print "{}: {}".format(wordDict_transpose.get(str(word), 'Unknown'), word)


directions: north
verbs: go
stop_words: the
nouns: bear
numbers: 5
```

Comment: And the lookup will be much faster too.